# Using OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper with DAO classes

Tags: android, sqlite, module, dao, inject

I'm using the following libs:

ormlite-android-4.28.jar
ormlite-core-4.28.jar
roboguice-2.0.jar
guice-3.0-no_aop.jar
guice-assistedinject-3.0-rc2.jar
android-support-v13.jar

All my injection services are working fine but Im having issues with the following scenario. I've created a DaoProvider as follows;

```
public class DaoProvider<T extends DatabaseEntity, ID> implements Provider<Dao<T, ID>>
```

My AbstractModule class looks like this;

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Dao<CityPersist, Integer>>() {
        }).toProvider(new DaoProvider<CityPersist, Integer>(ormLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getConnectionSource(), CityPersist.class))
```

My CityDao looks like this;

```
@ImplementedBy(CityDaoImpl.class)
public interface CityDao
    extends Dao<CityPersist, Long>
{
    ConnectionSource getConnectionSource();

    CityPersist create(JSONObject json);

    CityPersist findByCityId(String cityId);
}
```

The issue Im having is trying to create ConnectionSource in the AbstractModule. If using the roboguice 1 I can just set the following;

```
public ClientServicesModule(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper ormLiteSqliteOpenHelper)
    {
         super();
         this.ormLiteSqliteOpenHelper = ormLiteSqliteOpenHelper;
    }
```

By creating a new AbstractModule in my Application class. However, I've seen anywhere that allows me to create the same in roboguice 2.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution;

Updated by abstractmodules class as follows;

```
bind(DealsDao.class).toProvider(new DaoProvider<DealPersist, DealsDao>(OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DatabaseHelper.class).getConnectionSource(),Deal.class)).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

Then my helper class looks like this;

```
public class DatabaseHelper
    extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper
{

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Data.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private Dao<Deal, Integer> dealDAO = null;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    /**
     * This is called when the database is first created. Usually you should call createTable statements here to create the tables that will store
     * your data.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource)
    {
        try
        {           
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Deal.class);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {           
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is called when your application is upgraded and it has a higher version number. This allows you to adjust the various data to match the
     * new version number.
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {

    }

}
```

Now everything works! Its a combination of different solutions...